# How to get time for 1 looping program in ROS node?

Tags: ros, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS fans..

How to get time for 1 looping program in ROS node ??

I hope someone can help me ^_^

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64023/how-to-get-time-for-1-looping-program-in-ros-node-??/) by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-31**:
Please edit your question, adding some pseudo-code showing what you want to measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure exactly what you mean.

But if you want to know how many time does the loop you've written in a node last, you can use a time library.

I don't know about which library it is in C++, but in Python you can import 'time' and use the function 'clock()'. This function will return you the current date on your computer. Just call it at the beginning of the loop and have it printed in your terminal.

If you don't want to know the date but the time elapsed, just use a variable that your initialise once before the beginning of your loop and then, in your loop don't print 'clock()' value but clock() minus your initialised variable.

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0